# Relative paths to file issue in deploying an app

Tags: html, google-app-engine, polymer

I have a polymer app that I'm deploying to Google App Engine. It is step-2 of [the beginner polymer tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-2.html). I keep getting 404s and 500 errors for some resources, specifically these are the errors:

```
GET http://polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/images/avatar-07.svg 404 (Not Found) polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/:66
GET http://polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html 500 (Internal Server Error) polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/:10
GET http://polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/images/avatar-07.svg 404 (Not Found) polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/:66
GET http://polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/components/core-selector/core-selector.html 500 (Internal Server Error) polymer-test-nik.appspot.com/:78
```

The directory structure is unchanged from the tutorial.

I'm using a simple main.py to serve the app

```
import random
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
        i = random.randint(1,11)
        q = 'step-2/index.html'
    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

class GuideHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    q = 'icgt-registration-guide.pdf'
    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

Comment: Have you tried making your `components` and `images` folders a static directory? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_directory_handlers

Comment: In the case of the beginner tutorial, would this be the following? (SEE EDIT ABOVE) Cuz I tried the following and it doesn't work.


- url: ../components
  static_dir: components

and 

- url: ../images
  static_dir: images

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /components
  static_dir: components
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

It's worth noting that these handlers should be added *after* your `url: .*` declaration, otherwise it will catch all and never go further down, so in this simple example, the complete declaration will look like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /components
  static_dir: components
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

I will also recommend using the [webapp2 framework](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp2) instead, it's recommended for new applications and way better!

Comment: Done. But how should the url be structured in the html? Should it be ../components or /components or just components? My directory structure is the same as here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-tutorial

Comment: `/components`, the slash will make it look at the root of your app.