# How do I bring the Polymer project into Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, polymer

I have Google App Engine application that I would like to bring Polymer components into.  I thought the best way to start off would be to bring the [initial Project](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) into Google App Engine 
So I created my new Google App Engine Application using Google App Engine Launcher.  I then created my application on Google App Engine.

the URL for this test application is http://polymertvshelp.appspot.com/

So I then moved the Polymer project into my folder and uploaded it into Google App Engine

The application works landing on the page that displays the

> Hello world!

text.

So then I find a post that tells me some next steps but I am missing something.  the Post [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246008/relative-paths-to-file-issue-in-deploying-an-app)

In the post Mike the author gave me the code for the main.py which I modified by deleting the following

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

I then pasted Mike's code into the file

```
 import random
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
        i = random.randint(1,11)
        q = 'step-2/index.html'
    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

class GuideHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    q = 'icgt-registration-guide.pdf'
    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

this is the only code that executes in this main.py file now

I also modified the app.yaml file so that it looks like

```
application: polymerxxxx
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /components
  static_dir: components
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

I also modified the index.html in the step-2 folder by removing the .. in front of the relative paths.

When I run the application I now get 
500 server error

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please try again in 30 seconds.

I'm hoping someone can get me going because I sure would like to play with some of these components.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jamie Gomez again thank-you for your help.
I was able to make this work and wanted to share how I did it just in case someone else might have the same interest.

1. I created a new project with Google App Engine - python sdk
2. I ran the application with no changes
3. I made a 'templates' folder
4. I made a 'components' folder inside of that new 'templates' folder
5. I put all of my 'polymer' 'get Paper Elements' downloaded from the Google polymer project website (everything in the 'components' folder) goes there
6. I created another 'components folder at the root of my project (same level as my 'templates' folder)
   Note: Both 'components' folders need to contain the same items
7. in the templates folder I place an 'about_v2.html' the code is posted below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>About V2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
<H1>About Our Application</H1>
<br /><br />
<p><a href="components/paper-radio-group/demo.html" target="_blank">Paper Radio Group Demo</a></p>
<hr>
<H3>Links</H3>
    <a href="/">Home</a><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

8. I make my 'app.yaml' file look like

```html
    application: hellopolymer
    version: 2
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: yes

    handlers:
    - url: /favicon\.ico
      static_files: favicon.ico
      upload: favicon\.ico
    - url: /components
      static_dir: components
    - url: .*
      script: main.app

    libraries:
    - name: webapp2
      version: latest
    - name: jinja2
      version: latest
```

9. I made the 'main.py' look like the following

```html
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world! <a href="/about_v2.html">About</a>.<br />')
       
class AboutPage_v2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            
        }

        template = env.get_template('about_v2.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/about_v2.html', AboutPage_v2)],

                              debug=True)
```

10. I then ran the application and clicked on the links to get to my polymer page

Note: When I loaded this test app to the appspot.com I noticed that the polymer page works fine on my computer but doesn't work for my mobile device.

My guess... Appspot is not yet ready for Polymer.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you need to declare all your URL handlers *before* `url: .*`, because that will catch all, so your `app.yaml` should look like this:

```
application: polymerxxxx
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /components
  static_dir: components
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Now, your problem seems to be that you're mixing the **app.yaml** declaration of **python27** with the code of a **python25** app. For the older version, your *handlers* declaration would look like this:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

Notice how the declared script is the actual *python file*, which would be executed by the server.

Now, in the newest and recommended version of the framework, your application code should look something like this:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Notice how you just create the application and let the server pick it up, as per the *app.yaml* declaration (in your case, it looks for the `app` object in the `main` module).

[Learn more.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld)

Comment: Jamime, thanks for the information.  I am working through the import webapp2 code now. The rest of what you sent really went in fast.  I did have to mark threadsafe = no.  I hope to be back on here soon with a success message.  Regards, Chris

Comment: I am not having any luck with this so I am going to ask another question with the goal of simplifying things. I hope the the answer to that question will eventually help me find success here.